# Links not working in react-browser-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using `<Link>` elements from `react-browser-router` inside `<h3>` tags as follows:

```
<h3 className="title-signup h3-title">
  <Link to="/login" className="Link">
    Already Have an Acount?
  </Link>
</h3>
```

This is the route:

```
<Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
```

Comment: But how is the `/login` link supposed to correspond with the `/signup` route? The Route won't match?

Comment: this is the right link sorry ``` <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how you import is important.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Then how you create the Routers is important.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route path="/signup">
       <Signup />
     </Route>
     <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
     </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Finally, how the  is created is important.

```
<h3 className="title-signup h3-title">
  <Link to="/signup" className="Link">
    Already Have an Acount?
  </Link>
</h3>
```

Comment: i did this and the page just keeps loading now

Answer (score 1):

1. The `Link` should be imported from `react-router-dom` not from `react-browser-router`.
2. I kindly advise you to update your React knowledge. Instead of `<Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />`  you can write `<Route exact path="/login"><Login/></Route>`
3. Routing code should be wrapped inside `<Switch></Switch>`, `<div></div>` and `<Router> </Router>`. This step is very important, as @KAYRA noted.
4. If still not working, try to change place of Link and H1.

```
<Link to="/login" className="Link"> <h3 className="title-signup h3-title"> Already Have an Acount? </h3> </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

attribute value in Link to='...' and value path='...' in Route must be the same

```
<Route path="/login" exact component={Signup} />
```

Comment: yea this is what i have for my routes but it isnt working still ```<Route path="/signup" exact component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />```